# ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory when importing cv2 using Docker container

Tags: python, docker, opencv, streamlit

I was builting a web app with streamlit, OpenCV and Torch on local machine. The whole project went well until I built a Docker file and was about to transport it to my Google Cloud Platform. Can anyone tell me what is really going wrong here?
[image]

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:latest
RUN pip install virtualenv
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/venv
RUN virtualenv venv -p python3
ENV PATH="VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copying all files over
COPY . /app

# Expose port 
ENV PORT 8501

# cmd to launch app when container is run
CMD streamlit run app.py

# streamlit-specific commands for config
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
RUN mkdir -p /root/.streamlit
RUN bash -c 'echo -e "\
[general]\n\
email = \"\"\n\
" > /root/.streamlit/credentials.toml'

RUN bash -c 'echo -e "\
[server]\n\
enableCORS = false\n\
" > /root/.streamlit/config.toml'
```

And requirements.txt:

```
albumentations==0.4.5
matplotlib==3.2.2
numpy==1.19.0
opencv-python==4.1.0.25
# opencv-python-headless==4.2.0.34
pandas==1.0.5
Pillow==7.1.2
scipy==1.5.0
streamlit==0.62.0
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Maybe, you should run following command before `pip`.

```sh
apt update
apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxrender1 libxext6
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should do it separately or do it with dockerfile?

Answer (score 5):

Anyone encountering this issue and wanting to install a minimum number of external packages, this solved using `open-cv` and `torch` in one docker image for me:

```
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install\
    libgl1\
    libgl1-mesa-glx \ 
    libglib2.0-0 -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

P.S.: Notice how the combined apt-get update and apt-get install safe one layer.

P.S.S.: As huyu mentioned: include this in your Dockerfile before the `pip` command.

Edit: Thanks @gardner-bickford for suggesting to remove apt-cache to further decrease image size.

Comment: You might want to remove the apt cache files in that same layer:

rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

From: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/instructions/#apt-get

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error when trying to run the fresh  install of Anki flashcard program. Searched/installed missing "libgthread-2" via YaST2 Package Manager.